# Add contour lines to Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

I am writing the following code:

```
points = {{6, 2.12, .4738}, {8, 2.05, .5254}, {10, 1.99, .5520}, {12, 
    1.73, .5595}};
faces = {{1, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 4}};
colors = {32.4, 24.3, 19.2, 16.5};
color1 = (colors[[1]] - Min[colors])/(Max[colors] - Min[colors]);
color2 = (colors[[2]] - Min[colors])/(Max[colors] - Min[colors]);
color3 = (colors[[3]] - Min[colors])/(Max[colors] - Min[colors]);
color4 = (colors[[4]] - Min[colors])/(Max[colors] - Min[colors]);
pts = Map[toPoint, points];
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[ points, Polygon[faces], 
   VertexColors -> {RGBColor[color1, 0, 1], RGBColor[color2, 0, 1], 
     RGBColor[color3, 0, 1], RGBColor[color4, 0, 1]}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Axes -> True, Lighting -> Automatic]
```

The result is successful, but lacks contour lines for a 3D effect.  How can I add that feature?
[image: My image:]

Edit: pts is leftover code from something else.  It does nothing.
I am trying to get continuous mesh over the surface of both triangles to make them look more 3-dimensional.  The two surfaces in the attached image are in different planes, but they share a common edge.  I need contour lines or mesh to emphasize that these two surfaces are not in the same 2-dimensional plane.

Comment: But there is a mesh, it consists of two elements. I am not sure I understand what you are looking for?

Comment: @user21 Welcome back :)

Comment: @Öskå, thanks! I am here to get the FEM and computational geometry stuff started.

Comment: You might have a look at DiscretizeGraphics (Version 10 only)

[link](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/data-and-mesh-regions/discretizing-graphics.html)

Comment: what is `toPoint` ? not defined. You are not even using `pts` at all in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that regularly-spaced mesh parallel to the axes--not the mesh used to create the graphics--can only be drawn for `"*Plot"` type graphics (and not `Graphics3D`). Here is my attempt to draw it. Note that I don't know how to combine both types of meshes in one plot--I tried to use `BoundaryStyle` but it only drew the outline of the shape without the line running across it--so I just draw the plot twice and highlight different features of the graphics.

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[points, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize@Large}] (* vertices *),
 ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> 50] (* regularly spaced mesh *),
 ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  PlotStyle -> None] (* outline mesh *)]
```

---

**Edit**: mixing `ListPlot3D` for the surfaces and `Graphics3D` for the lines and vertices will give you the same results without having to use `ListPlot3D` twice.

```
Show[
 ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> 50],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points], Red, Thick, 
   Line[Subsets[points, {2}]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit 2**: I spoke too soon. There is an errant line below the surface of the graphics, which makes sense since one can draw 6 lines connecting 4 points whereas the graphics only needs 5 lines to draw. I used `Manipulate` to find out where that line is and manually remove it from the list of lines will give the graphics without the extra line below.

```
vp = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
Column@{Dynamic@vp,
  Manipulate[Show[
    ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> 50],
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point[points], Red, Thick, 
        Line[#[[i]]], Black, Thin, Line[#]},
        Axes -> True] &@Subsets[points, {2}], 
    ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]], {i, 1, 6, 1}]}
(* i = 2 in control*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[
 ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> 50],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points], Red, Thick, 
   Line[Delete[Subsets[points, {2}], 2]]}], ViewPoint -> vp]
(* you can leave the ViewPoint option out when evaluating this plot *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit 3**: Should have thought about this much earlier but I think the best solution would be to just plot a (white) mesh over your entire `Graphics3D` using `ListPlot3D` with `PlotStyle -> None` (to make the plot transparent except for the mesh lines), and appropriate `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` options. This way your formatting for the graphics can be conserved.

Also, I find 1-direction mesh lines work better in this case than 2-, hence the `{#1 &}` in `MeshFunctions`. You can of course change it to `{#1 &, #2 &}` to make them go in 2 directions, or even `{#1 &, #2 &, #3&}` for 3 directions, though at that point the mesh starts to appear very busy.

```
Show[
(* this was your graphics *)
 Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[points, Polygon[faces], 
    VertexColors -> {RGBColor[color1, 0, 1], RGBColor[color2, 0, 1], 
      RGBColor[color3, 0, 1], RGBColor[color4, 0, 1]}]}], 

(* just add this ListPlot3D below it and wrap everything in a Show*)
 ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> 100, MeshStyle -> White, PlotStyle -> None,
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}], 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]